# How to delete training characters without annoying `E486: Pattern not found` error?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to automatically delete trailing characters at the end of line (on save). According to [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces) I create the following mapping:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>rt :let _s=@/<Bar>:%s/\s\+$//e<Bar>:let @/=_s<Bar>:nohl<CR>
nmap <silent> <leader>w <leader>rt:write<CR>
```

The problem is when there is no trailing characters the `E486: Pattern not found: \s\+$` is occur and interrupt the next `:write` command. I tried to search something similar to my problem, but get nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is `:silent[!]` command. You can do:

`:silent! %s/\s\+$//`

The `!` lets `silent` also skip error messages. But the `v:errmsg` was set anyway.

Read `:h :silent` for details.